# Mobility should save all record attributes shouldn't it?

Tags: ruby, mobility

I added a *virtual* attribute to a record via `attribute` like this.

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility

  attribute :hint
  translates :hint, type: :text
end
```

Works so far. Even the by Mobility added methods like `question.hint_fr=` etc. are available. Now I assumed Mobility would on `question.save` also create the corresponding `Mobility::Backends::ActiveRecord::KeyValue::StringTranslation` record, but it doesn't. Why doesn't it? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

---

**Update**: I fall into a *trap*. I had the option `column_fallback true` set and then when `Mobility.locale` and `I18n.default_locale` where the same, for some reason the attributes translation was not saved. If I disable the option `column_fallback` then the translation gets saved as expected.

It seems for me that Mobility never saves a translation if `Mobility.locale` and `I18n.default_locale` are the same. Which caused some headache to me because together with the `column_fallback true` option this leads to rather unexpected behaviour. Imagine `I18n.default_locale` is `:de` and `Mobility.locale` too and then you map fallbacks to e.g. `{:fr => :de}` which on record attribute access an environment with `Mobility.local = :fr` then leads to `nil` because the `:de` translation actually does not exist.

Comment: It appears you have solved this for your self, so rather than an **Update**: 1) If you believe this Q/A would benefit future SO visitors then I would recommend posting your update as an answer (yes it is okay to answer your own questions); 2) If you do not believe this to be of benefit to future SO visitors then I would recommend deleting the post.